# Log transformation results in a negative coefficient

Tags: logistic, data-transformation, regression-coefficients, logarithm

I am running a logistic regression with 7 independent variables. One of these variables is income. If I don't log-transform income and run the regression, it results in a positive coefficient, however, when I log-transform it, it results in a negative coefficient.

Why would this happen?

Comment: Are there observations that have negative or zero income? Are there any interactions between income and other variables?

Comment: Is the variable statistically significant in either or both of the regressions?

Comment: @jbowman Yes, they are both statistically significant

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov I'm not sure what you mean by the first question. But there is some interaction between income and other variables. Could this be why its happened?

Comment: Log of zero or negative values is not defined, so that could change the sample between the two regressions if those observations get dropped because of missing ln(income) data. Second, interactions in non-linear models [are tricky](http://datacolada.org/57). Even the sign is often not very directly interpretable.

Comment: Plot residuals! Try modeling income as a spline

Answer (score 2):

I can think of several reasons why this could happen.

1. The relationship between the logit of the DV and the IV is nonmonotonic, either with the original IV or the log of the IV or both, and taking the log changes the sign of the linear relationship. In this case, you should model the relationship using either polynomial terms or a spline.
2. The IV has outliers that affect things differently when it is logged.
3. The IV is nearly colinear with one of the other IVs, either when it is logged or in its original form.

In any case, you should decide whether to log the IV based on substantive grounds and then work on finding a good model. Income is often logged because we think about income multiplicatively rather than additively. That is, if you are making \$20,000 and get a \$5,000 raise, that's huge.  If you are making \$200,000 and get a \$5,000 raise, it's not.